# Sharing article on LinkedIn with description and image

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

Why is it that I can't have both an image and a description, when I share an article on Linkedin? They are both defined in my metatags and I can see both in the preview, but the final post will only have the image, and if there is no image it will have the description.

```html
<meta property="og:description" content="Some description">
<meta property="og:title" content="Some title">
<meta property="og:image" content="/path_to_image">
```

I have read [their documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) but it doesn't mention that it is not a possibility to have both.